# How do I delete selected grid row programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to add and delete rows dynamically in the **datagrid**. This is the code that I use to add rows by using the click property of an add button:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        private void AddRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        }
```

similarly I want to create a delete button and delete the selected row how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove element from your data source, which is in this case `DataTable dt`. Just use the following code to remove selected row from the table:

```
private void DeleteRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGrid1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your delete button to a command with a parameter.
The parameter will be your Grid.SelectedItem

then when you handle command you will have selected item, do whatever you wish to do with it.

see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665546/Passing-Command-Parameter-for-Buttons-within-an) for command parameters.